# using ruby, how to create hexBinary data required by hudson's postBuildResult?

Tags: ruby, hudson

I'm wanting to submit build results to hudson via a ruby script. What little documentation I can find says the data within the  tag is in "hexBinary" format. How do I take a simple ruby string like "Hello, world" and convert it to that format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about hudson, and am not positive that the following is hexBinary.  But here is my best stab at it.

```
"Hello world".unpack("H*")  # => ["48656c6c6f20776f726c64"]
```

So to just get the string...

```
"Hello world".unpack("H*").first
```

I am confused about the hexBinary format, as I couldn't find any definitive examples on what it really is.